# install4j - Windows how to make installed files read only

Tags: windows, install4j

With install4j Windows installer how do you make installed files read only?

I see how you do it with Unix file mode but now Windows.

Comment: What are the default attributes the files get? you can always change them afterwards with `attrib +r`, too.

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 6.0 there is no action to change the Windows file attributes.

You can add a "Run executable or batch file" action with the "Executable" property set to

```
${installer:sys.system32Dir}\attrib.exe
```

and the arguments set to

```
+r ${sys:installationDir}\*.* \s
```

Use the editor for that property and put each argument on a separate line.

See the [help for attrib](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) for more information.